# JDBC ResultSet total rows

Tags: java, jdbc, pagination, resultset, rowcount

I am implementing Paging in my application. For this I run a query and get a ResultSet.
Now I want to get total number of records in this ResultSet for my paging calculation.
How can I get this ? I don't want to execute extra SQL which gives me total rows.

Comment: Just curious is this a web application? If we are not talking about 1000+ records from the query, you can very easily implement a java script pagination and avoid having to hit the backend for each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to add the count aggregation as a sub queried column in your query. If your database is just a little bit smart, it will only execute that once. You should be able to check this easily using the query analyzer in your favorite database.

```
SELECT id,username,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users) FROM users;
```

Comment: i recommended using java solution because if we have a complex query this will has a performance cost

Comment: Unless you are using a database with a very primitive query optimizer, counting the number of rows in the result set will be no more costly than doing it later on the Java side.

Answer (score 2):

The *normal practice* is to map the `ResultSet` to a `List<Entity>` where `Entity` is a javabean representing the actual data, e.g. `User`, `Product`, `Order`, etc.

Then, you can just use `List` methods like [`List#size()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29) to obtain the rowcount.

```
List<Entity> entities = entityDAO.list();
int rows = entities.size();

if (entities.isEmpty()) {
    // It is empty!
} else if (entities.size() == 1) {
    // It has only one row!
} else {
    // It has more than one row!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually i dont want to get all rows in a collection because i want to display only 10 rows on page thus my paging calculation helps me to get only 10 rows from resultset. For this i need total no of rows in resultset.

Comment: Then fire two queries: one to get the `COUNT(*)` (or better, `COUNT(pk)`) and another to get the rows of interest. Although pribably not fully suited for your requirement (JSF webapplication), you may get some useful insights out of [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
int totalRows = 0;
    try    {
        resultSet.last();
        totalRows = resultSet.getRow();
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
    } catch(Exception ex)  {
               return 0;
          }
    return totalRows ;
```

Comment: Call resultSet.getRow() directly returns me 0. Now I see it means how many rows the resultSet's current location to the beginning. I wander why it's designed like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the default behavior for a ResultSet is not to obtain all the rows at once, so there is no way to know from the object itself how many rows would be returned from the query without first iterating (and thus retrieving) all of them. You might get different behavior with specific JDBC drivers for specific databases.

May I ask why it is too costly for you to run a COUNT() query first ? Compared to the cost of retrieving the actual values, it shouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: is this best practice, To run a query to get count ? Is there any way ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best practice, but if you run a count query first (e.g., SELECT COUNT(*) as NumExpectedRows FROM table WHERE whatever;), you could predict the number of rows you would get from the resultset without building the whole set. Databases should optimize this (check with your specific vendor docs). The caveat is that the number of rows should not change until you perform the "real" query.

Comment: yes, the count could change between the two queries, so it may be inaccurate. But in this application, the count could also change between the time that the user requests page 1 and page 2, so we can't guarantee perfect accuracy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment to [BalusC's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040108/jdbc-resultset-total-rows/3040141#3040141) answer:

> [...] Actually i dont want to get all rows in a collection because i want to display only 10 rows on page thus my paging calculation helps me to get only 10 rows from resultset. For this i need total no of rows in resultset

You want nothing but asking the database for about 10 rows **and** the size of the table. so you actually have two (2) questions to your data store which is equal to two (2) select queries. Do it as [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040108/jdbc-resultset-total-rows/3040139#3040139) suggested and don't care about 'best practice'. If one day someone comes around with a better practice you still can decide whether to adapt your code or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in counting List size to get record count, as we are implementing pagination and SHOULD NOT load entire resultset at a time.

I use ROW_NUM at database level to implement pagination logic. We need to get the as many records as we need to show it on the screen.

Example: select * from Emp where rownum>=:beginRecord and rownum<=:endRecord

***** Logic will be the same but syntax may change depending up on the type of the database. Need to use nested query if we need to do order by of any column.*

I believe, count(*) is expensive operation, rather i prefer partition by.

**Select Eno, Ename , (select count(*) from emp) as record_count from Emp -- Expensive
Select Eno, Ename , count(*) over (partition by eno) as record_count from Emp -- Preferred one.**

***** Partition by syntax may change depending up on the type of the database.*

I have considered Oracle database.

Answer (score -1):

in addition to Fathah solution you can use this code, also note that because its a memory pointer this solution has no performance issues:

```
int totalRows = 0;
if(rowSet.last()) {
   totalRows = rowSet.getRow();
}
rowSet.beforeFirst();
```